# Trouble using Threading with Redis (Jedis) in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, redis, jedis

I have a Scala program using threading (actually Spark) and Redis (Jedis). I defined an `object` for my Redis operations where I have a `Lazy val` for the connection. I need each thread to open a connection to Redis and work with it in parallel.
**The connection object:**

```scala
object redisOp{
  lazy val r = new Jedis("127.0.0.1",6379,30)
  def find(u: Long): Option[Long] = Option(r.get(s"p$u")).flatMap(p => if (p.toLong == u) Some(u) else find(p.toLong))
  // and other functions
}
```

When I use it with one thread, it works well. But when multiple threads using it I get errors. At first, I got `Unknown replay: 4` in each thread, where "4" is a random character (`redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply:`).
Then from `redis-cli` I tried to set `config set timeout 30000` and `30000` as I also saw a `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream` and sometimes `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length` in logs as well. And now in some runs(when switching to 2 threads instead 4), the program stucks in a stage forever with no errors! I checked Spark-UI to check executors' log but can't find anything useful: https://pastebin.com/iJMeBD0D

I think the problem is in defining and using connection with Redis. Also, please tell me the proper way of closing the connection if needed.

Comment: IMHO, instead of updating the question, you should create a new question (only with the updated part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jedis object is not thread-safe. You should use some sort of object/connection pooling in a multi-threaded environment. Jedis provides JedisPool for that purpose. More details can be found in [Jedis Wiki](https://github.com/redis/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#using-jedis-in-a-multithreaded-environment).

The basic idea is to get Jedis object by `JedisPool.getResource()` and return that object by `Jedis.close()`.

Comment: Thanks. So I will have a "pool" instance in my singleton, then for each function I `getResource()` first, do the job and then `.close` it, right?  
Isn't it costly for each thread to open/close the connection by each function call?

Comment: Connections won't be opened/closed at each function call rather those will be reused. If Jedis is part of a JedisPool, behind the door, `.close()` won't actually close the connection but would declare that it is free to reuse. It (.close) is included in this process to take the advantage of Java's try-with-resource paradigm.

Comment: I still have problems where I need to increase `.setMaxIdle(8000)` and `.setMaxTotal(8000)` otherwise the program stucks! I need help! this is my connection now: https://pastebin.com/Z8LKuXTF